# Whats the standard tool to develop on the Windows Phone Platform?

Tags: apps

Is this Windows Visual Studio, or is there a dev environment more attuned to the Windows Phone Platform?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this would be Visual Studio 2013. The Windows Phone SDK is included since Update 2. You can either use the regular, paid version if you have it or make use of the free Express version.
http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk

Comment: There is also App Studio...